# How pass this values in PHP

Tags: php, html, drupal

I think this is a very basic question, but I am searching for two hours and can't find anything what works :-(

I have a Drupal Webform to collect personal information about my users and send it to another page with Drupal module "Webform Remote Post" (It removes "submitted").

The name attributes of the input tags look like this:

```
<input name="submitted[address]">
```

I can use this data in PHP like this:

```
$address = $_POST['address'];
```

But the problem are the Date fields. Here the name attributes look like this:

EDIT: It is an select element!

```
<select name="submitted[date][day]">
```

EDIT: I already tried this:

```
$day = $_POST['date']['day'];
```

How can I get the day value with $_Post?

Thank you!

Comment: `$_POST['date']['day'];`

Comment: Ah sorry, I already tried this, but it only gives the value "1" :-(

Comment: are you sure you have only one field like, <input name="submitted[date][day]">? and the html format is same as you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, there is only on field <input name="submitted[date][day]">. Additionally I have <input name="submitted[date][month]"> and <input name="submitted[date][year]">. The html format?

Comment: `name="submitted[address]"` should result in `$_POST['submitted']['address']`…!?

Comment: I use Drupal module "Webform Remote Post" and it removes "submitted".

Comment: If you're getting "1" then that's a valid value, what are you expecting? "Monday"? In which case `date('N', $_POST['date']['day']);`

Comment: have you dump your post ? echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);? check your post data, may it is setting in hidden field

Comment: 1 more trick, change date index <input name="submitted[date][day]">, use this <input name="submitted[my_date][day]">, just for testing

Comment: @ naththedeveloper  I need the value which is given there, the day of the month. I try to get the date of birth.                    @Muhammad Akber Khan I can't change this, it is given by the Drupal webform module.

Comment: what i am understand, is you have three fields in your form like month, day, year => and you want to use these combination to get birthdate right?

Comment: @Muhammad Akber Khan Yes, but I need them as single values to send them to an API-Service.